# Reasons against using local indexes

Tags: oracle, index, partitioning

For Oracle 10g and above: except in cases where a local index cannot be used and a global index is needed (e.g. unique constraint), is there any reason to favor a global index over a local index?

Answer (score 2):

There is a point where the queries using the index are accessing enough partitions that a local index will be slower than a global index.

For example, if your table is partitioned by date, but you are querying only on a status column.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Leigh points already to the main backdraw.

But his answer is true only, if cardinality of matching records is very small.
It would definitely be poor, if to be searched column has unique or almost unique values (but this is often not the case for status columns).
In such case, many local indexes will be accessed with very low success rate, which generates high useless I/O and is very inefficient.
In such cases, a GLOBAL INDEX works much more efficient.

However, it depends on number of partitions, partition-sizes in relation to the number of matching records.

If you select bigger amounts of records and the chance to find them in many of the partitions, then this backdraw is not really relevant anymore. This is often the case for status columns, having only a few different values.

For example:

Having a table with 100 partitions, e.g. by DATE and you want to search just for a status column:
If cardinality of matching records is let's say 10000, then you will probably find records in each partition. In such cases, you will have no real benefit from a GLOBAL index, although it might be some milliseconds faster. But the benefits of the LOCAL indexes often overcome such backdraws.

Another reason against LOCAL INDEXES might be, that Index maintenance requires more knowledge. E.g. Rebuilding a LOCAL index cannot be done like GLOBAL index by just "ALTER INDEX xxx REBUILD", because each partition needs to be addressed and rebuild.
This can be a big advantage during 24/7h operation, but some people don't like such efforts.